# Unique index on 3 columns with 2 mutually optional

Tags: postgresql, index

Given this table

```
create table contacts (
    customer int not null,
    phone char not null,
    facebook_id char not null
    /* some other fields */
)
```

- I'd like to make sure there can't be two rows with the same `(customer, phone)` or `(customer, facebook_id)` or `(customer, phone, facebook_id)`.
- If there is a duplicate `(customer, phone)` during an `INSERT`, I'd like to update `facebook_id` with the incoming value, and the other fields.
- If there is a duplicate `(customer, facebook_id)` during an `INSERT`, I'd like to update `phone` with the incoming value, and the other fields.
- If there is a duplicate `(customer, phone, facebook_id)` during an `INSERT`, I'd like to update other fields.

I could create 3 separate unique indexes but I wouldn't be able to use the `ON CONFLICT... DO UPDATE` clause which need a single index inference. I can't either omit the index inference (and let Postgres bump into the first conflict) because `DO UPDATE` needs it.

How should I solve this problem ?

PS: empty `''` values can be inserted and must be considered null (i.e. should not be considered duplicates). I can make those fields nullables if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like flawed requirements. I suggest you split and have two tables, one with `(customer, phone)` to store the phones and another with `(customer, facebook_id)` to store the facebook ids of each customer.

If you also want to have the original table with the 3-column unique key, in order to store what combinations of phone and facebook ids each customer is using, you can keep it as well.

The suggestion becomes - I also assume you have a `customer` table:

```
create table customer (
    customer_id int not null,
    constraint customer__PK
        primary key (customer_id),
    customer_name text
    /* other customer attributes */
) ;

create table contact_phone (
    customer_id int not null,
    phone text not null,
    constraint contact_phone__PK
        primary key (customer_id, phone),
    constraint contact_phone__customer__FK
        foreign key (customer_id) 
        references customer,
    phone_source text
    /* other attributes related to customer - phones */
) ;

create table contact_facebook (
    customer_id int not null,
    facebook_id text not null,
    constraint contact_facebook__PK
        primary key (customer_id, facebook_id),
    constraint contact_facebook__customer__FK
        foreign key (customer_id) 
        references customer,
    facebook_source text
    /* other attributes related to customer - facebook */
) ;
```

and your original `contacts` renamed to `contact_combo`:

```
create table contact_combo (
    customer_id int not null,
    phone text not null,
    facebook_id text not null,
    constraint contact_combo__PK
        primary key (customer_id, phone, facebook_id),
    constraint contact_combo__contact_phone__FK
        foreign key (customer_id, phone) 
        references contact_phone,
    constraint contact_combo__contact_facebook__FK
        foreign key (customer_id, facebook_id) 
        references contact_facebook,
    combo_source text
    /* other attributes related to customer     */
    /* and combination of phone and facebook_id */
) ;
```

The `INSERT` procedure is going to be slightly complicated and depending on requirement details (e.g. do you allow a customer to be stored with only phone and without facebook, is it possible to have a customer without known pone or facebook, etc) but there will be no problem with using `ON CONFLICT .. DO UPDATE` as each table has a single unique constraint.

Comment: After a lot of thoughts and for the sake of simplicity I'm going to merge both fields into one (`external_id`) and add a `external_id_kind` field (either `phone_number` or `facebook_psid`). It's not likely a contact would've had both `phone_number` and `facebook_psid` fields filled in anyway. Thanks for spending time writing your solution which I'm sure would work but would've been too complex for the use case.